# Set jQuery slider max value dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, jquery-slider

I am using [jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) in a `grid view`. assume there are 3 rows in `grid view`. so there are 3 sliders. i need to set 3 values for max value of these three sliders.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

try the max option,

```
<script>
  $(function() {
     $( "#slider" ).slider({  max: 50  });
     $( "#slider2" ).slider({  max: 90  });
     $( "#slider3" ).slider({  max: 30  });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try looking at API [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/)?

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({ max: 50 });
```